# How to limit characters in paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a angular application and I want to limit the characters in a paragraph(p).
So that it will give a return after say 50 characters.

So I have this template:

```html
<section class="echeq-element-html-display border-box"
    [ngClass]="{isYoutubeVideo: isYoutubeVideo}"
    [innerHTML]="doHtmlDisplay(echeqElement)"
></section>
```

ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-html-display',
  templateUrl: './html-display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./html-display.component.css']
})

doHtmlDisplay(eCheqElement: EcheqElement): SafeHtml {
  return this.returnSafeHtml(this.getHtml(eCheqElement));
}
```

and this is my css:

```css
p {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* will make [...] at the end */
  width: 50px; /* change to your preferences */
  white-space: nowrap; /* paragraph to one line */
  overflow: hidden; /* older browsers */
}
```

But this doesnt work.

So what I have to change?

Thank you

there is also a main.css:

```css
p {
  margin: 0 0 0.75em;
}
```

But of course I just want to get a maximum characters for that component not in the entirely application.

in ts script, I have it now like this:

```
truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
    let element = document.querySelector(selector),
      truncated = element.innerText;

    if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
      truncated = truncated.substr(0, maxLength) + '...';
    }
    return truncated;
  }
```

and in template:

```
<section  class="echeq-element-html-display border-box" (input)="truncateText('p', 10)" [ngClass]="{isYoutubeVideo: isYoutubeVideo}" [innerHTML]="doHtmlDisplay(echeqElement)"></section>
```

But nothing changes.

Comment: Can you give echeqElement example content ?

Comment: You will not use pure javascript right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your css should work, check the value of `white-space` in browser dev tools

Also you can try to do this in typescript

```
document.querySelector('p').innerText = truncateText('p', 50);

function truncateText(selector, maxLength) {
    var element = document.querySelector(selector),
        truncated = element.innerText;

    if (truncated.length > maxLength) {
        truncated = truncated.substr(0,maxLength) + '...';
    }
    return truncated;
}
```

Comment: Thank you . But I am using angular. How can I use this: document.querySelector('p').innerText = truncateText('p', 50);

Comment: use it when you detect change in p i.e. when user starts writing

Comment: I mean where in the ts script?

Comment: And by the way it is a read only input field. It comes from a tinymce input field

Comment: then when you render the text to this input field apply it there

Comment: or use (input)="truncate()" in html and write code in ts function

Comment: I get this error: Declaration of instance field not allowed after declaration of instance method. Instead, this should come at the beginning of the class/interface. (member-ordering)tslint(1)

Comment: because you wrote the first line `document.....` in side class

Comment: write it in some function where you are giving value to your input filed

Comment: @NiceTobeBottleInfinity Define function `truncateText` within the component class & `document.querySelector('p').innerText = truncateText('p', 50);` inside `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below

```
doHtmlDisplay(text, limit = 50) {
 if (text.length > limit) {
  text = text.substring(0, limit);
 } else {
  text;
 }
 return text;
}
```

and in your HTML

```
<section class="echeq-element-html-display border-box"
[ngClass]="{isYoutubeVideo: isYoutubeVideo}"
[innerHTML]="doHtmlDisplay(echeqElement, 100) | safeHtml"></section>
```

Use the `safeHtml` pipe

Comment: You can use slice angular Pipe
{{youtText | slice:0:20 }}

Comment: it gives error when we use slice with [innterHTML]